JS Modules are not downloaded with import statement
I am building a PWA with Typescrip. My ts.config "compilerOptions" are:
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
   "outDir": "Build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
},

In my app I have 4 ts files: app.ts, x.ts, y.ts, z.ts.
app.ts imports from x.ts, y.ts and z.ts and does not export anything.
x.ts, imports from y.ts and z.ts, and exports to both of them.
y.ts imports from x.ts and z.ts and exports to both of them.
z.ts imports from x.ts and y.ts and exports to both of them.
my index.html file loads app.js as module.
I expect that when app.js is loaded, the import statement will automatically trigger the downloading of x.js, then y.js, then z.js.
However, when I insepct the app sources, none of x.js, y.js, z.js is downloaded. Even app.js does not appear in the tree.
In the browser console, I get the follwing error:
   GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/Build/modules/x net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
:5500/Build/modules/x.js?cache-bust=1720247349006:3 
    
    
   GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/Build/modules/y net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
:5500/Build/modules/y.js?cache-bust=1720247349006:3 
    
    
   GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/Build/modules/z net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Before getting to this app.js, x.js, y.js, z.js structure, I had tried many other combinations. In all of them, I noticed that the "import" statement does not load the file.
It is the first time I work with modules. I Can any one explain to me why the import or export * from "filePath/name" does not download the script?

What does it mean when you say "it exports to both of them"?  You import specific scripts, but you don't export to specific scripts, you just export and anyone who imports you can get those exports.

Your description (or at least the part I think I might understand) sounds like perhaps you have circular dependencies which is not allowed in Javascript.  You can't have a import b and b import a.

by "it exports to both of them", I mean that a exports variables and functions that are imported by b and c; while b and c are each exporting variables and functions that are imported by a.

However, I guess the problem is not that I have circular dependencies. I tried making script A only exports variables and functions, then script B imports from A, then script C imports from A and B, then script D imports from A, B, and C, and so on. I still get the same error: actually the scripts are not downloaded as files.

Well, if you had a circular situation, then the TypeScript compiler would probably recognize it and give you an error and not produce the various  JS files.  Other than this guess, there's not enough information in your question to help further since you show no code for the relevant modules and show none of the compiler output.

Then, by your second comment, you clearly have a circular dependency.  Can't do that.  You can't have two modules both importing each other.  Break the common things out into a separate module and have each import the common things.  Your module design is messed up.  Modules should not be importing modules that are also trying to import you.  That's a messed up module design.
